# Change the font size of all the forms in windows application in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, font-size

I have already created windows application using Windows forms and i have many form in that. Now i want to change the font size of all the forms and it is not possible to go into each form and change the font size.

So, i need to know is there any way to change the font size of all the forms from one place.

Thanks

Comment: Even if you find a quick-shot way to change the font size of all the forms, it might deform the layout of many controls.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add slightly to this, if you want to change the font of all of the controls within the form, I wrote this piece a few years ago, but has held up pretty well... Have a go if will help?

Just call in the form Load_Event.. or wherever you need

```
Public Sub Form_Load()
    Checkfont(Me)
End Sub

Public DifferentFont As Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 10)
Public Sub CheckFont(frm As Form)
    If Not USE_Different_Font Then Exit Sub
    For Each ctl As Control In frm.Controls
        If ctl.HasChildren Then
            CheckFont_Children(ctl)
        End If
        Try
            ctl.Font = DifferentFont
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub CheckFont_Children(parent As Control)
    For Each ctl In parent.Controls
        If ctl.HasChildren Then
            CheckFont_Children(ctl)
        End If
        Try
            ctl.font = DifferentFont 'New Font(DifferentFont.FontFamily, DifferentFont.Size)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```